# Cannot unlock from graphical screen

Tags: 13.04, gnome-screensaver

I cannot unlock my Ubuntu 13.04 from the unlock screen. It immediately returns to the lock screen, even if the password is right.

I need to to enter the VT and do DISPLAY=:0 gnome-screensaver-command -d

To unlock. The fact that I can enter the VT, and log in at initial lightdm means my PW/KB is right.

Auth log:

Sep 28 16:13:11 sean-Aspire-4736Z dbus[1074]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.58" (uid=1000 pid=2480 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-session/indicator-session-servi") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.14" (uid=0 pid=1641 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")

Comment: I observed this situation when disk was full.

Comment: I have 2.8G left. Entering a bad password and then after getting the invalid password message, entering the right one results in the unlocking working.